# The converse of the Cartan theorem on Lie subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

As stated by Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem

> the closed-subgroup theorem (sometimes referred to as Cartan's theorem) is a theorem in the theory of Lie groups. It states that if H is a closed subgroup of a Lie group G, then H is an embedded Lie group with the smooth structure (and hence the group topology) agreeing with the embedding.

But can we take the converse for granted like: Any Lie subgroup $H\subset G$ that is a Lie subgroup of a Lie group $G$ is a closed Lie subgroup.

The example I was thinking of is the Poincaré group where the $SO(1,3)$ group is clearly a Lie subgroup of the Poincaré group by construction. So can I say that $SO(1,3)$ is a **Closed** Lie subgroup of the Poincaré group?

Thanks for responding.

Comment: Use `[description](link)` for links.

Comment: thank you for the remark @Shaun

Comment: What's a Lie subgroup of $G$ for you. I suppose that it is a subgroup of $G$ which is also a submanifold. If so, which definition of submanifold are you using? There are two standard ones, and the answer to your question depends upon this.

Comment: My idea of a Lie subgroup is a subgroup that is a Lie group and in the example, the fact that we know that $SO(1,3)$ is a (Lie) subgroup of the Poincaré group which is a Lie group makes me want to apply the converse of the Cartan theorem. And I am not using a particular definition of a submanifold.